# Default value for the second element of the map STL?

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures, stl

what is the default value for second element in map STL if i am initializing it with an array?
for example:

```
 #include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
  
void countFreq(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    unordered_map<int, int> mp; 
  
    // Traverse through array elements and 
    // count frequencies 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        mp[arr[i]]++; 
  
    // Traverse through map and print frequencies 
    for (auto x : mp) 
        cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl; 
} 
  
int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = { 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 20, 5, 20 }; 
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
    countFreq(arr, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

How can this program return the frequency of the element in the array by accessing the second element of map mp?

Comment: The default value for items not in the map is 0.

Comment: @drescherjm Assuming you use operator[]

Comment: Yeah, the new mapped value is [value initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). For an `int` that means [zero initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

Comment: but then how this program can give the frequency of the element present in the array?

Comment: When `mp[arr[i]]++` executes it either increments an existing value or, if necessary, creates a new key-value pair and zero-initializes the value before the increment.

Comment: The description of what happens is in [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at). It might not be clear if you're new to C++ documentation but the details are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the default value for the second element in map STL if I am initializing it with an array?

When accessing a key-value pair (kvp) in a `std::map` with `operator[]`, either the key already exists, or a new kvp is constructed and the `mapped_type` is [value-initialised](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). A value-initialized `int` is always 0. This imposes a requirement that it must be default constructible. Note that you can also access entries in a map using the [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) member function, which throws if the key is not found.

> How can this program return the frequency of the element in the array by accessing the second element of map mp?

You have done this correctly in your code snippet. You could have used a [`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) or [`std::unordered_multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset), they provide a [count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/count) member function, that is the frequency of the key.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int arr[] = { 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 20, 5, 20 }; 
    std::multiset<int> freq (std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));

    for(auto elem = freq.begin();
        elem != freq.end();
        elem=freq.upper_bound(*elem)) // Traverse the unique elements
    {
        std::cout << *elem << " count: " << freq.count(*elem) << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:6,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:6,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Cset%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%0A%7B%0A++++int+arr%5B%5D+%3D+%7B+10,+20,+20,+10,+10,+20,+5,+20+%7D%3B+%0A++++std::multiset%3Cint%3E+freq+(std::begin(arr),+std::end(arr))%3B%0A%0A++++for(auto+elem+%3D+freq.begin()%3B+elem+!!%3D+freq.end()%3B+elem%3Dfreq.upper_bound(*elem))%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+*elem+%3C%3C+%22+count:+%22+%3C%3C+freq.count(*elem)+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:53.197814832943635,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B14%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.80218516705635,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:46.80218516705635,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

---

Note that your question mentions `std::map` but the example you provided references `std::unordered_map`, much of this applies to both data-structures.

Answer (score 0):

Second element of map is, by default, initialized to 0(if its type is int as is in code) after trying to access its key at least once.So, when you access for the first time some element x, mp[x] becomes 0 and then in your code increases by 1 when counting.